# How call a json with get data in php

Tags: php, json

How can i call/send a "GET" method json with data, in php

like, `http://mydomain.com/jsons/getEmployeeDetails.json/<empID>/<empCode>`

I've tried with

```
$json_file = file_get_contents(http://mydomain.com/jsons/getEmployeeDetails.json/<empID>/<empCode>);
$data = json_decode($json_file, true);
```

but its not returning data, json cancelled.

Comment: Are you getting syntax error? :^)

Answer (score 2):

You should quote your URL with quotes. Example:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

PHP will actually issue a parsing error. Turn on display errors option to view the errors (via php.ini or `ini_set()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $json_file = file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com/jsons/getEmployeeDetails.json/<empID>/<empCode>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('[data-toggle="modal"]').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "<?= base_url();?>mobilephones/mobiledetails",
          data: { mid: id }
        })
          .done(function( data ) {

            var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON (data);

            $("a").attr("href", "<?= base_url();?>mobilephones/editmobilephone/"+json_obj.id);

            $("#m_title").html(json_obj.title);
            $("#m_brand").html(json_obj.brand);
            $("#m_model").html(json_obj.model);
            $("#m_network").html(json_obj.network);
            $("#m_camera").html(json_obj.camera);
            $("#m_os").html(json_obj.os);
            $("#m_processor").html(json_obj.processor);
            $("#m_sim_size").html(json_obj.sim_size);
            $("#m_internal_memory").html(json_obj.internal_memory);
            $("#m_exp_memory").html(json_obj.expandable_memory);
            $("#m_display_resulation").html(json_obj.display_resolution);
            $("#m_display_size").html(json_obj.display_size);
            $("#m_color").html(json_obj.color);
            $("#m_from_price").html(json_obj.price_from);
            $("#m_to_price").html(json_obj.price_to);
            $("#m_description").html(json_obj.description);
            $("#m_features").html(json_obj.features);
            $("#Tags").html(json_obj.tags);
          });
})
```